# Dropzone inside Vue transition modal doesn´t work

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

i have a dropzone function in mounted function, it works fine when in the view the dropzone is outside of a modal, but in transition modal doesn´t work, any idea or solution for this?

this is .ftl

```
...
<transition name="modal" id="deletemo">
   <div v-if="uploadModal" >
       <div class="modal-mask">
           <div class="modal-wrapper">
               <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                         <div class="modal-header">
                              <h5 class="modal-title">upload file</h5>
                              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" @click="uploadModal = false">
                                 <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                              </button>
                          </div>
                          <div class="modal-body">

                              <div class="form-group">
                                 <label>select file type</label>
                                 <multiselect placeholder="Seleccione tipo de fichero" v-model="fileTypeSelected"  :options="fileTypelist" > </multiselect>
                                                                      
                               </div>
                                                                    
                               <div class="form-group">
                                   <div class="animated fadeIn">
                                        <div class="card">                
                                           <div class="card-body">
                                               <div id="uploadFile" class="dropzone col" style="border-style: dashed;">
                                                       <div class="dz-message" data-dz-message>
                                                           <div>upload file here ...</div>
                                                       </div>
                                               </div>
                                            </div>
                                         </div>
                                      </div>
                                  </div>
                              </div>
                              <div class="modal-footer">
                                   <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" @click="uploadModal = false">Close</button>
                              </div>
                         </div>
                     </div>
                   </div>
               </div>
          </div>
   </transition>
```

.js

```
 mounted:   function () {
                    var vue = this;
                    dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
                    $("div#uploadFile").dropzone({ 
                        
                        url: "/demo/uploadFile"
                       ,acceptedFiles: ".pdf"
                       ,clickable: false
                       ,maxFilesize: 100
                       ,addRemoveLinks: true
                       ,init: function() {
                           
                            this.on('success', function(file, json) {
                                  
                            });
                            this.on('addedfile', function(file) {
                            });
                            this.on("sending", function(file, xhr, formData) {
                                formData.append("nif", vue.filePerson);
                            });
                            this.on("complete", function(file) {
                                //this.removeFile(file);
                              });
                        }
        
                    });
                }

    });
```

I was looking for other similar post but not for a transition , so it does not work for me.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

After trying multiple things i found the solution using an attribute "v-on:enter="enter" in transition and inside function initialize dropzone.

```
<transition name="modal" v-on:enter="enter" >
  ...... 
</transition>


enter: function () {
  
         $("div#uploadFile").dropzone({ 
                            
             url: "/demo/uploadFile"
             ......
         });
       },
```

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced the same issue. I this the problem is mostly the `v-if` div:

```
<div **v-if=**"uploadModal" >
   <div id="uploadFile" class="dropzone col" style="border-style: dashed;">
      <div class="dz-message" data-dz-message>
          <div>upload file here ...</div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

VueJS seems to take control of everything happening there, to enable the dropzone, you will need to use `@click` or something to that effect. We just need to create the method that will be responsible for opening the FileInput:

```
methods: {
  openDropZone() {
      const dropzone =  Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {
        url: "http://localhost:8000/upload",
        maxFiles : 2,
        addRemoveLinks: true,
        headers: {
            "X-CSRFToken": "{{ csrf_token }}",
        },
      };
    dropzone.hiddenInputFile.click();
  }
}
```

Then we call the `openDropZone()` method from `@click`:

```
<div v-if="uploadModal" >
   <div id="uploadFile" **@click="openDropZone()"** class="dropzone col" style="border-style: dashed;">
     <div class="dz-message" data-dz-message>
         <div>upload file here ...</div>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```